# Cable diameter, included wire diameters, and connection to breaker

Tags: electrical

I am preparing to replace a 50a breaker in a Siemens box with a 100a Siemens breaker, and then run a 2/0-2/0-2/0-1 SER cable to a new subpanel in the same house.  The 50a breaker I intend to remove once was connected to a 4-4-2 (XHHW-2) AL line that served an electric cooktop which has now been replaced with a gas cooktop.

My tentative plan is to use the old electric cooktop cable to pull the new, bigger cable up through the floor and into the box.  I expect I will run into considerable difficulty due to the significantly larger O.D. of the new cable.  I have two questions to pose to your cadre of experienced electricians.

1. I presume it is against code to take the jacket off and separate the wires that comprise the cable before those wires enter the box (for one reason, because the naked ground would be outside the box).  Correct?
2. I am too new at this to know whether I'd have to buy a "properly sized" or "properly typed" new 100a breaker so it can receive the two new 2/0 AL wires.  Can just any 100a Siemens breaker accept large 2-0 wires that are AL instead of Cu?  Will there be any problem attaching the large 2-0 neutral or 1 AWG ground?
3. I will have to go through some joists.  I plan on drilling a 1 1/4" hole in the center of each joist to pass the new service cable through to the new subpanel.  The new cable that I have not yet purchased is reported to have about a 1 1/8" O.D.  I have seen comments on the web about needing to avoid "over filling" conduit (i.e. filling beyond stated table limits) against code because heat increases to danger points, etc., and I wonder if that principle would also affect constrictive situations without conduit.  In other words, do I need to drill big enough holes to allow the cable to be able to be "rattled" a bit, eliminating all constriction whatsoever.  I know that on a 2x10, a hole can not be larger than 3"dia. and no closer than 2" from the top or bottom, but I want to drill the smallest holes possible to maintain the greatest joist strength. Advice?

Comment: Joists and conduit are two different things.  In conduit the heat cannot escape well.  In a joist there should be some air to remove the heat and only a tiny length(~1.5 inches).

Comment: 2/0 AL is awfully large - it's good for 135A at 75C. Why are you using that instead of #1?

Comment: I was planning to use 2/0 because my possible future use of the subpanel could include a split A/C unit, A 3 hp table saw, a 2hp dust collector, a Tesla large sized car charger

Comment: I also was planning on a 100 amp breaker but thought I saw that 1/0 AL wire was only rated for up to 95a.

Comment: According to https://www.compas.siemens-info.com/COMPASWebPage/Catalog/index.html#!?spinId=Q2100&altImgSrc=1 (can't find an actual text spec sheet) the Q2100 breaker will accept wire sizes from 6-2/0 directly on its terminals.

Comment: Standard wire ampacity chart: https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/

Comment: WOW, THANKS Nobody.  I guess I misread or looked at the wrong chart.  Apparently I can use 1-1-1-3 AL cable.  Muchas Gracias.

Comment: You should really run a full load calculation (which is **not** just adding up breaker sizes) on your existing main panel to see how much capacity you have, and on the subpanel you're planning to see what the actual demand is. It's possible you'd be fine with a 90A circuit (and very economical #2 SER cable), especially if you're willing to pause EV charging for a bit while you're doing your woodworking.

Comment: Thanks, Nobody.  I did the load calc on the main panel and believe I have room to add the Q2100 Siemens breaker.  You saved me money on the suggestion I check the chart again, since I did and will now use 1-1-1-3 AL cable instead of 2/0-2/0-2/0 cable, the diff in cost between 2 AWG AL and 1 AWG AL cable not being much.  And I will certainly clamp on the jacket after receiving your confirmation that is way to meet code reqs.  THANKS.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are connect that you may not strip a cable outside of a box. This has nothing to do with exposed bare grounds being forbidden (metal conduit is routinely used as a ground conductor in exposed/accessible locations, and exposed bare wire may be used for retrofitting ground for installations that pre-date grounding). It's about the fact that the cable's rated integrity (against heat, chafing, etc) depends on the presence of the whole cable. The clamp that secures the cable to the box must clamp on the cable jacket.
2. The Siemens Q2100 two-pole 100A circuit breaker terminals accepts wire sizes 6-2/0, copper and aluminum, and are rated 75C.
3. Be aware that large-gauge cables are very "lumpy" as the conductors are formed into a spiral inside. You can get away with less margin on the hole size the thinner the material you're going through. A 1 1/4" hole in a 2x10 for a 1 1/8" cable (so 1/16" margin on either side) seems... optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

> I presume it is against code to take the jacket off and separate the wires that comprise the cable before those wires enter the box (for one reason, because the naked ground would be outside the box). Correct?

That only works if a) the individual wires have their own identifying markings for insulation type, manufacturer, UL listing, size, etc. ..... And, you are putting the individual wires to a use legal for those wires.  You can't run individual XHHW wires loose in a wall; having shucked them out of an cable sheath does not make that legal.

> I am too new at this to know whether I'd have to buy a "properly sized" or "properly typed" new 100a breaker so it can receive the two new 2/0 AL wires. Can just any 100a Siemens breaker accept large 2-0 wires that are AL instead of Cu? Will there be any problem attaching the large 2-0 neutral or 1 AWG ground?

Well, 2/0 is a dumb size.  The largest breaker that will fit in 2 spaces is 125A, and 1/0 aluminum wire is 120A.  I would stick to 1/0 as you'll find terminals to be more receptive.

> I have seen comments on the web about needing to avoid "over filling" conduit (i.e. filling beyond stated table limits) against code because heat increases to danger points, etc., and I wonder if that principle would also affect constrictive situations without conduit.

It doesn't apply for one cable, no.

If you were grouping five or more 20A circuits, we'd need to have a conversation.

> a Tesla large sized car charger

Do you really have a 400 mile daily commute?

People with no experience with EVs tend to be drawn like moth to flame to the "Fastest Charge Possible".  This starts a chain of stupidity, because everyone (including your electrician) assumes EV charging is a World War I technology, to which power must be provisioned the same as fork lift or hot tub.  Money is needlessly wasted putting in the Fattest Feeder Possible, and we see as much as $10,000 entirely wasted on this with service upgrades, fat feeders, you name it.

Yes, SAE and Tesla have heard of "silicon" and emply 1980s era microcontroller tech (well that's unfair to the 70s, since the 1977 Apple II had all the necessary tech) to do things a little bit smarter.

For instance, a 60A circuit is overkill for home (it's for hotels when a large F150 Lightning sized EV arrives at 10% charge and needs 100% by morning to continue travel).  At home you're only replacing your daily commuting needs, and then you want a 50-100% margin for reasonably quick recovery after road trips.  So if your commute is 50 miles, conservatively a 20A (240V of course) circuit will suffice.

But let's say we go bonkers and go 60A.  Now, what are the needs of your wood shop?  Whichever is larger is all the feeder requires.

Because a $300 kit can be added to the subpanel's 65A feeder wires, and tied to the EVSE.  The EVSE charges at full 48A, but when you start the dust collector, EV charging slows to 44A, and when you spin up the saw, it slows to 31A.  When you finish your cut, charging bounces back up to 44A.   (not quite like that, I'm sure you know the saw's current varies by force of cut; pushing the work through faster makes it draw more current.)

So you only need to size your feeder for the wood shop *or* the EVSE, not both at once. The saw and A/C run infrequently enough not to have a big impact on overall charging.

And by the way, that should be a heat pump, not an A/C, so you don't need to run costly strip heaters or fuel heating.

Comment: HARPER -  This is really good info and thus really appreciated.  LOVED the EV charging advice and will just forget worrying about it.  I am not going to add a charger now.  I was just thinking that adding enough juice for one might improve the home's appeal for the next buyer when I finally have to downsize or be "put away" Hah!  Because I commented in the wrong place (I guess), you may not have noticed that based on the advice I got here I will now use 1-1-1-3 AL cable to run from a Q2100P Siemens 100 amp breaker (instead of a 2/0-2/0-2/0 cable AL cable).  THANKS SO MUCH !!

Comment: HARPER - I forgot to tell you that you were also right about the future unit being a HEAT PUMP.  Thanks Again!  (Am still admiring what you taught me about the car charger.  Really good info.!)